# Infinite series using definite integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$S_{n} = \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^{2}-1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^{2}-4}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n^{2}+2n-1}}$

Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_{n}$

My  views on the question:

1. Tried to find the nth term of the series (without any luck)
2. Figured that by taking n common from each of the terms 1/n is created which caused me to think that somehow this series may be redefined as a definite integral.

Please help me in finding the nth term of the series and also tell whether this question can be solved using integration.

Comment: So $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-k^2}}$, is it?

Comment: Oh, yes it is. That didn't strike me at all.

Comment: To address someone use @username , in this way he will be notified.

Comment: I didn't know that. Will keep that in mind

Comment: Thanks @MANMAID

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n^2-k^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-(\frac{k}{n}})^2}=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

A slight change of variables from MANMAID's answer makes it look a bit simpler, to me at least:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{4n^2-k^2}}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac k{2n}\right)^2}}\frac1{2n}\\
&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\[3pt]
&=\left.\arcsin(x)\vphantom{\int}\right]_0^{1/2}\\[9pt]
&=\frac\pi6
\end{align}
$$